# Proving if $\varphi(c) \in \Sigma$ then $\exists x \, \varphi(x) \in \Sigma$ for a maximal consistent set

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

Let's say $\varphi$ is a formula and $\Sigma$ is a set of formulas. Let's then say that $\Sigma$ is a maximal set. All I know about maximal sets is that either $\varphi \in \Sigma$ or $\lnot\varphi \in \Sigma$ (where $\varphi$ is a formula). So using that definition, if $c$ is a constant then how can I prove that if $\varphi(c) \in \Sigma$ then $\exists x \, \varphi(x) \in \Sigma$ if $\Sigma$ is a maximal consistent set (consistent just means the formulas in $\Sigma$ will never lead to a contradiction in a derivation).

Comment: Hint: Consider the conjunction $\varphi(c) \wedge (\forall x)(\neg \varphi(x))$. Is this in $\Sigma$?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your brackets. Is x a free variable?

Comment: If x is supposed to be bounded by ∀x then I would say this wouldn't be in Σ.

Comment: No. It's bound by the $\forall$... I just put parentheses around quantifiers. And yes, that is correct, now use the fact that $\Sigma$ is maximal and consistent.

Comment: You'll use consistency as follows, after you negate the conjunction, it becomes, $\neg \varphi(c) \vee (\exists x)(\varphi(x))\in\Sigma$. Since $\Sigma$ is consistent, you cannot have $\neg \varphi(c)\in\Sigma$. So you must conclude $(\exists x)(\varphi(x))\in\Sigma$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by contradiction. If, by absurd, $\exists x \, \varphi(x) \notin \Sigma$, then $\lnot \exists x \, \varphi(x) \in \Sigma$ by maximality of $\Sigma$. But then $\Sigma$ would not be consistent, because from $\varphi(c)$ and $\lnot\exists x \, \varphi(x)$ you can easily derive a contradiction, as the following derivation in natural deduction shows.

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\lnot\exists x \, \varphi(x) \qquad \dfrac{\varphi(c)}{\exists x \, \varphi(x)}\exists_\text{intro}}{\bot}\lnot_\text{elim}
\end{align}

Therefore $\exists x \, \varphi(x) \in \Sigma$, since $\Sigma$ is consistent.

Comment: Why couldn't I just say that ∃xφ(x)∈Σ because of ∃intro?

Comment: @JoshSusa - No, you can't. Indeed, _a priori_, we don't know if $\Sigma$ is closed by derivability. By closure by derivability I mean that if $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ (i.e. if $\varphi$ is derivable from $\Sigma$) then $\varphi \in \Sigma$. The only hypotheses about $\Sigma$ are maximality and consistence.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco - Wouldn't we need to establish completeness for your proof to hold?